# Why scaling down the parameter many times during training will help the learning speed be the same for all weights in Progressive GAN?

Tags: matrices, normal-distribution, machine-learning, gradient-descent, python

The title is one of the special things in [Progressive Gan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10196.pdf), a paper of the NVIDIA team. By using this method, they introduced that

> Our approach ensures that the dynamic range, and thus the learning speed, is the same for all weights.

In details, they inited all learnable parameters by normal distribution $N(0,1)$. During training time, each forward time, they will scale the result with **per-layer normalization constant from He's initializer**

I reproduced the code from [pytorch GAN zoo Github's repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch_GAN_zoo)

```
def forward(self, x, equalized):
    # generate He constant depend on the size of tensor W
    size = self.module.weight.size()
    fan_in = prod(size[1:])
    weight = math.sqrt(2.0 / fan_in)
    '''
    A module example:

    import torch.nn as nn
    module = nn.Conv2d(nChannelsPrevious, nChannels, kernelSize, padding=padding, bias=bias) 
    '''
    x = self.module(x)

    if equalized:
        x *= self.weight
    return x
```

At first, I thought the **He constant** will be $c = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n_l}}$ as [He's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf). Normally, $n_l > 2$ so $w_l$ can be scale up which lead to the gradient in backpropagation is increase as the formula in ProGan's paper $\hat{w}_i=\frac{w_i}{c}$ $\rightarrow$ prevent vanishing gradient.

However, the code shows that $\hat{w}_i=w_i*c$.

I asked this question on some communities e.g: StackOverflow, Artificial Intelligent, and still haven't had an answer.

In summary, I can't understand why to scale down the parameter many times during training will help the learning speed be more stable.

Please help me explain it, thank you!